# Android Java Socket Mobile Phone to PC -- Reconnect socket

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have been going crazy about the android app I'm developing.
I'm making a socket like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IPAdress, Port);
```

And when I freshly installed the app, it works perfectly fine. 
But then I close the app (close the server as well, restart the server).
I call

```
socket.close();
```

when destroying my app (onDestroy).
When I restart the app, I can't connect again, I need to manually delete the app from the cash, then it works again.

Same thing happens when I enter a wrong IP Adress. I can't just reenter a new Adress and try making a new socket again. I do it like this:

```
socket.close();
socket = null;
Socket socket = new Socket(IPAdress, Port);
```

It doesn't let me do it.
I am creating the new socket in a new  `Thread`

Comment: We'll need some more code or an actual Error.

Comment: I will copy them in a second :)
Also, how do you make the code look like it's taken from an SDK?

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part, but I *guess* you mean "How do you get the markup for code with syntax highlighting?". In this case, indent your code by four spaces or use the "code"-button in the editor. If this is what you meant, you're referring to an IDE, not an SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart" the app? And for that matter what do you mean by "app" and "onDestroy" (an Activity, or an actual Application object)? Just a guess (without code), but from the description (it works again if you delete the app) it sounds like you have some lifecycle related issues, you may not be actually setting up and tearing down your socket where you think you are if the app/activity doesn't actually get destroyed.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I tried to indent my answer below with four spaces, it didn't work :( And yes, what I was referring to was an IDE :D I got so messed up on that android problem I was having!!

Comment: Also, sorry I didn't post anymore code here, I don't know how to do this but if you guys see this post to be useless, just tell me how to delete it or maybe you can delete it :)
@CharlieCollins on my Android app, I indeed had some Lifecycle issues :) Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know how to deal with it but now I do ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy` is not the right place to close the socket. It's called only when the system is low on resources.

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing with the socket, but if you don't need it when the application is no longer visible to the user, you should close it in `onPause` or `onStop`.

See the application lifecycle in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the reason on why my app kept crashing when calling. 
The socket kept being alive even with the app closed, because it remains in the cache. 
So when exiting the app I have a boolean which tells me if I have a valid socket at all, then I'm able to close it. If I wasn't able to open a socket, I don't need to close it.

Then on restart, I simply do this:

socket = null;

then I can create a new socket!

(Sorry for not being able to properly indent and format this text, I tried it with four spaces, but that didn't work :(